# Typescript: Type inference with union types and ternary operator

Tags: typescript, ternary-operator, union-types

The following typescript code compiles just fine:

```
let x: 0 | 1 = 0;

console.log(x);

const r = [true, false];
for (const y of r) {
    if (y || (x !== 1)) {
        x = 1;
    } else {
        x = 0;
    }

    console.log(x);
}
```

However this code, which is semantically equivalent does not:

```
let x: 0 | 1 = 0;

console.log(x);

const r = [true, false];
for (const y of r) {
    x = ((y || (x !== 1)) ? 1 : 0);
    console.log(x);
}
```

Error for the `x !== 1` is:

```
7:17 error TS2367: This condition will always return 'true' since the types '0' and '1' have no overlap.
```

In both cases, running the compiled result yields the expected output showing that x does in fact take the value 0 *and* 1:

```
0
1
0
```

I understand the error stems from the fact that the compiler narrowed down the type `0 | 1` to just `0` in the  second case. However, just by looking at the code it is clear that it *could* be that `x` is assigned 1 (even without looking at the condition). Thus, I would expect type inference to assume the most general type unless explicitly told otherwise (as it does in the first example). In fact, in line 1 I explicitly tell the compiler that I want the more general type: `let x: 0 | 1`.

So my question would be if there is a sensible reason why the type inference behaves differently in case of the ternary operator?

Answer (score 1):

The error is actually because the compiler has narrowed the type of `x` to `0`.

I'm not sure why you don't get the error in the other case - as I would expect it to be consistent in both cases - but I'm not smart enough to write the tools that do this stuff.

Example where the type of `x` is forced to be `0 | 1` rather than the compiler narrowing it to zero:

```
let x = 0 as 0 | 1;

console.log(x);

const r = [true, false];
for (const y of r) {
    x = ((y || (x !== 1)) ? 1 : 0);
    console.log(x);
}
```

Comment: As you can see from the output, x takes the value 1 after the first loop run. In the second run the condition does evaluate to false (differently from what the compiler says) -- which is why x is set back to 0.

Comment: I don't think I'd call the error "correct".  It's more like one of the many [tradeoffs in control flow analysis](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998); in this case, during [initialization](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8513).  The compiler narrows the type of `x` to `0` and then gets angry later about comparing it to `1`... but of course `0 | 1` should be comparable with `1`.  Often the narrowing is helpful, but here it is not.  It can be avoided by initializing as `let x = 0 as 0 | 1` or by comparing like `(x !== (1 as 0 | 1))`.

Comment: But why is this trade off then not showing in the first case where the CFA works just fine in determining the type of x as `0 | 1`? It makes no sense to me

Comment: @jcalz - edited to remove the ambiguity - you're right about the mis-use of the word "correct". I also updated the example to be more like an actual solution.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough: I totally understand why the error is there (narrowing of the type `0|1` to `0`). My argument is that this behavior is in fact incorrect and inconsistent to normal behavior:

Simplest case: `let x: 0 | 1 = 0; x = 1;` works like a charm -- the compiler correctly restrains from narrowing as it detects that during program run x can in fact take both values. A more complex case is my example above where it also works fine.

What I want to know is if there is a sensible reason for this deviant behavior because if not I think this should be marked as a bug.

Comment: If you do `let x: 0 | 1 = 0; x = 1;` it will complain if you compare `x` to `0`. It's the same issue.

Comment: The issue seems to be that when the loop is first entered, `x` is definitely `0` and `1` is definitely `1`, and because the way the typings for `!==` work, it won't let you compare them. I agree it's weird behavior; my guess is to "fix" it would involve re-widening upon entering a loop in which an assignment occurs, and that might break other use cases.  You can report it if you want (or search for an existing issue, #8513 is related) but I don't know if they will do anything... it's a trade off; heuristics have false positives and false negatives.